# eclipse codestyle: insert blank linkes before methods > 1 line

Tags: eclipse, coding-style

I want the eclipse code formatter to do what I've tried to describe in the title: Inserting blank lines before methods ONLY when those are > 1 line.
Current Settings:
New Lines => Keep braced code on one line => Method declaration => If at most one item.
Blank Lines => Blank lines within class declarations => Before method declarations => 1. (here I want to differentiate).

Code should look like this:

```
...
public void setVal(int val) { this.val = val; }
public int getVal() { return val; }

public void doMore() {
    getVal();
    getVal();
}

public void doEvenMore() {
    doMore();
    doMore();
}
...
```

But looks like

```
...
public void setVal(int val) { this.val = val; }

public int getVal() { return val; }

public void doMore() {
    getVal();
    getVal();
}

public void doEvenMore() {
    doMore();
    doMore();
}
...
```

Would appreciate any solution.

Comment: In the built-in Eclipse formatter, the idea is to set how many blank lines should be preserved. This allows you for example to group getter and setter that belong together without losing the grouping by formatting (preserve: 1, between method/constructor: 0). Blank lines depending on the number of lines contained in the method are not supported. By the way, according to your description you are using an outdated Eclipse version with less formatter settings than the current version.